# Which communities (tags(s)) on SO award the most points for Q's/A's?

Tags: discussion, tags, stack-overflow

Just out of curiosity, which communities (i.e. tag(s)) on SO award the most points for questions?  How about for answers?  Anecdotally I've found that some communities are more willing to award points than others.  So I was just curious about which community is the most generous and which is the least generous.

As I said...purely out of curiosity.

Comment: [perl] is a goldmine

Comment: @random - I have been wondering for a long time why that is.

Comment: I judiciously upvote in [perl]. If it's right, it gets an upvote. Besides, there's usually more than one way to correctly answer a Perl question, so that might factor into it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few Stack Exchange data explorer queries that give insight on this:

- [Most/Least dangerous tags among those with 1000 questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/86/most-and-least-dangerous-tags-to-answer-among-the-tags-with-1000-questions)
- [Most rewarding tags to answer among those with 1000 questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/26/most-rewarding-tags-to-answer-among-the-tags-with-1000-questions)
- [Most lucrative tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/991/most-lucrative-tags)

And of course, you can bend the data explorer to your will to figure out what fits your chosen criteria best!

Comment: So finally we've come to admit it's been all about profit! :)

Comment: Apparently the Internet Explorer developers aren't happy people. =)

Comment: The Most Lucrative Tags query always shows a timeout for me.